# Can we rearrage the second derivate doing this:

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There is a homogeneous of degree 1 function $I=f(T,M)$, we find the first derivate:
$$
\frac{\partial I}{\partial M}
$$
Next, we take the derivate with respect to T:
$$
\frac{\partial I}{\partial M}\frac{\partial}{\partial T}
$$
Is this a true statement?
$$
\frac{\partial I}{\partial M}\frac{\partial}{\partial T}=\frac{\partial I}{\partial T}\frac{\partial}{\partial M}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Hint: what connection is there, if any, between the continuity of a given function and the order of partial derivatives?

Also - if you are applying $T$-differentiation **after** the initial $M$- differentiation, then I think your second quantity should rather be $\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial M}\right)$.